# Order of File Deletion in Bash

Tags: bash, files, rm

I'm surprised that I was not able to find this question posted already, but is there an definitive order in which files are deleted when using `rm -r`? For context, I accidentally began deleting a large directory that I did not intend to, and I want to confirm what was lost. I noticed that a large portion of first (alphabetically) subdirectory was missing but have not identified missing files in any other immediate subdirectory. Are files deleted alphabetically? Can I confirm the integrity of the remaining subdirectories?

Comment: I don't know, but I've assumed it was directory.entry order, ie. `ls -f` order, so unless you know what was there before hand you cannot know (and it may depend on file system used etc).  But note this is opinion, or educated-guess.

Comment: This has an answer here <https://stackoverflow.com/a/31250292/8133920>.